# Is there a way to add my own HTML and CSS files into GitHub-Pages without having to use Jekyll layouts?

Tags: github, github-pages

I want to create my own website and have been working on the page using Bootstrap and my own CSS style sheet. Is there a way of just pushing my HTML and CSS files straight to GitHub-pages without using Jekyll?

Here is a simple project structure of my files:
[image]

The index.html is the home page and the other pages are accessed from the nav-bar. The CSS files are linked to each HTML file as well.

Any information or links to tutorials is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indicate that you don't want GitHub Pages to build your page with Jekyll by adding an empty file called `.nojekyll` in the root of your publishing source (see [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#static-site-generators)).

You can also use a [custom GitHub Actions workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-with-a-custom-github-actions-workflow) to publish your page; such a workflow usually has four steps:

1. Check out the repo with [`actions/checkout`](https://github.com/actions/checkout)
2. Build your site using a static site generator
3. Upload your static files with [`actions/upload-pages-artifact`](https://github.com/actions/upload-pages-artifact)
4. Deploy the artifact with [`actions/deploy-pages`](https://github.com/actions/deploy-pages)

In your case, you can skip step 2, as you don't need to build anything. [This starter workflow](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/9d8124219fd36617f14290690d99e0a95bd318f1/pages/static.yml) does that.